# I have an extra page in the begins of my article

Tags: theorems, lncs

I have these in the start of my article

```
% This is samplepaper.tex, a sample chapter demonstrating the
% LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings;
% Version 2.20 of 2017/10/04
%
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
%
%

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section] 
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem} 
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition} 
\newtheorem{corollary}[lemma]{Corollary} 
\newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture} 
\newtheorem{construction}[lemma]{Construction} 
\newtheorem{example}[lemma]{Example} 
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition} 
\renewcommand{\Gamma}{\varGamma} 
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon} 
\renewcommand{\bar}{\overline} 
\renewcommand{\hat}{\widehat} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cir}{Cir}

\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant} 
\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant} 


%Extra things that are included for simplicity. 

\newcommand{\Po}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} 
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} 
%
% 
\newcommand{\Sym}{\mathrm{Sym}} 

\newcommand{\vt}{\mathrm{vert}}
\newcommand{\conv}{\mathrm{conv}}
\newcommand{\Fix}{\mathrm{Fix}}
\newcommand{\Span}{\mathrm{Span}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{conv}} 
\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}} 
\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{Cir}}
```

when I make pdf I have an extra page in the beginning .whith these two lines

```
Lemma[section] [lemma]Theorem [lemma]Proposition [lemma]Corollary [lemma]Conjecture [lemma]Example [lemma]Definition
```

why is that for and how I can fix it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: just compile this code with \begin{document } jjj \end{document }

Comment: Please make a MWE.

Comment: please fix your example to be a complete document and provide a link to the llncs class that you are using.